# How to append +/- signs in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I modify this script so that I can add any text in the button.  I just want to append the + or - sign instead of all the text.

JAVASCRIPT

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    function changeText(text) {
      return (text.indexOf('+') >= 0) ? 'Shop Now -' : 'Shop Now +';
    }

    $(".dropbtn").click(function() {
      var $this = $(this), $dropdownActive = $('.dropdown-active');
      /* changing the text of the active button (if any) */
      $dropdownActive.text(changeText($dropdownActive.text()));
      /* hiding the content under the active button (if any) */
      $('.dropdown-content', $dropdownActive.parent()).slideToggle('show');
      if (!$this.hasClass('dropdown-active')) {
        /* changing the text of the clicked button */
        $this.text(changeText($this.text()));
        /* showing the content under the clicked button */
        $('.dropdown-content', $this.parent()).slideToggle('show');
        /* adding this class to the clicked button */
        $this.addClass('dropdown-active');
      }
      /* removing this class from the active button */
      $dropdownActive.removeClass('dropdown-active');
    });

    // Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
    window.onclick = function(event) {
      if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
        var $dropdownActive = $('.dropdown-active');
        /* changing the text of the active button (if any) */
        $dropdownActive.text(changeText($dropdownActive.text()));
        /* hiding the content under the active button (if any) */
        $('.dropdown-content', $dropdownActive.parent()).slideToggle('show');
        /* removing this class from the active button */
        $dropdownActive.removeClass('dropdown-active');
      }
    }
```

thanks!!!

https://jsfiddle.net/jf1zetLw/11/

Comment: where do you want to append  + or - ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jf1zetLw/13/ Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

You should check if there is a `+` sign to replace it with a `-` or if there is a `-` to replace it with `+` like this:

```
function changeText(text) {
  if(text.indexOf('+') >= 0) // if we have a +
    return text.replace('+', '-'); // return the text after replacing + with -
  return text.replace('-', '+'); // otherwise return - replaced with +
}
```

Or a shorthand like yours:

```
function changeText(text) {
  return (text.indexOf('+') >= 0) ? text.replace('+', '-'): text.replace('-', '+');
}
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hrga5bua/).